# How do I get the first day of the given year's day of the week in Bash Shell?

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I have a bash script, where I am trying to pass in the year and get the first day of the week of January 1st of that year.

I have tried using the date command:

```
yearsago=$(( 2021 - year))
date --date="$(date +'%Y-%m-01') - ${yearsago} year "
```

No luck. For example, if I enter in the year: 2020 as a variable. It should find the first day of that year, which is January 1st, and find the day of the week for January 1st, 2020.

Output would be if Monday, print "1", if Tuesday, print "2"
Thank you.

Comment: Where in your script you output the day of a week? `- ${yearsago} year` ? Why not just `date -d "${year}`? why substract, if you know the year?

Comment: @tmiliketurtles does the solution I provided works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below code which will give you 1 first day of the year passed:

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
year=2020
firstday=`date -d "01 Jan $year" +'%A,%d'`
echo "First day of the year '$year' is : '$firstday'"
```

Output:
***First day of the year '2020' is : 'Wednesday,01'***
If you want to just get the day , then remove the %d option.

```
firstday=`date -d "01 Jan $year" +'%A`
```

Output :***First day of the year '2020' is : 'Wednesday'***

Answer (score 1):

> get the first day of the week of January 1st of that year.

Seems trivial:

```
date -d "$year-1-1" +%a
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a number instead? For example, Tue = 2? Thank you

Comment: Read `man date`, it explains all available modifiers. Then research how to do arithmetics in shell, see arithmetic expansion, research modulo and division operator to change the number range.

Comment: Got it, it is %u. Thank you